# seting cookies and load it in another page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a login page in that three fields are there.After login, in the next page there is a form in that the same fileds are coming.So i have to get the details from the login page to these fields;using cookies? i am attaching my code below

Comment: So where is the code

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 maybe we should consider that the whole code (0 characters) is posted?

Comment: Once a cookie is set for a domain, you can read that cookie from any page within the domain, so this won't be a problem.

Comment: It seems that your code is stolen by aliens. Btw it's not a good idea using cookies for what you are tryng to do. It's better use Session variables

Answer (score 2):

As @Tinwor said, using cookies **isn't** a good idea since cookies *are included in every server request* and this can slow down the user. `sessionStorage` is a better idea because it is most secure, faster and can store more data (at least **5MB**).

You can learn more about the usage, differences and capabilities of `sessionStorage` and `localStorage` [**here**](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Also, note that HTML5 Web Storage **isn't supported in older browsers**, but you can create a cookie fallback for it easily.